# activemq 2 listeners grails

Tags: grails, activemq-classic

I'm using the activemq plugin in grails. when I deploy 2 war files that make use of activemq in tomcat, tomcat never finish starting up. Is it because of port in used on something?

My service method in WAR A:

```
def jmsService
static transactional = false
static exposes = ['jms']


@Queue(name='msgs.new')    
def createMessage(msg) {}

    jmsService.send(queue:'msgs.new', json.toString())
```

My service method in war B

```
def jmsService
static transactional = false
static exposes = ['jms']


@Queue(name='msg.new')    
def createMessage(msg) {}

    jmsService.send(queue:'msg.new', json.toString())
```

Comment: Nope, is it because I have too many war files?